# Can't create alias for 'nano ~/.bash_profile'

Tags: terminal, bash

I tried to make an alias to edit my bash profile, but when I save and relaunch a new window, I get the following:

```
Last login: Sun Jul 22 12:00:25 on ttys001
-bash: alias: nano ~/.bash_profile: not found
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$

### manually reopen a new terminal

Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ ebp
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$
```

My .bash_profile looks like :

```
# edit bash profile
alias ebp= 'nano ~/.bash_profile'
# alias rbp= 'source .bash_profile'
```

Also fwiw, my other aliases work fine. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `ebp=` and `'nano ~/.bash_profile'` and the alias will work.